# Handling UserNotFoundException in PreAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have two authentication providers. One checks against the database and the other is a pre-authenticated provider for SAML assertion.

User information and their respective roles are persisted in a DB. So when the user hits  application with SAML, we insert a row in the database and assign a default role after which redirect the user to a registration page where we capture some user specific information.

With PreAuthenticatedProvider I am catching UserNotFoundException and the question is how do I redirect the user to registration page from my authenticate method?

```
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
           // custom code
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
           // Redirect user to a view
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way of handling such cases?

**EDIT:** I am interested in handling AuthenticationExceptions coming from AuthenticationProviders particularly PreAuthenticationProviders.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own Custom `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and put it in the filter chain before the form processin filter to catch these exceptions and handle properly.

Something like this in the application-context.xml

```
    <bean id="customExceptionFilter" class="com.company.module.security.filters.CustomExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="savedRequestCache"></constructor-arg>
        <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="customAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </bean>
```

Your ExceptionTransalationFilter need to extend `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and Override the `doFilter` Method:

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException
    {
        try
        {
            super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                    // Handle the exception here
            logger.error("Exception - ", ex);
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            if (SecurityHelper.isAjaxRequest(request))
            {
                writeFailedAjaxResponse(response, ErrorCode.INTERNAL_ERROR);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ServletException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Look under 8.2 Here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html